# SQL Server Copy Database Issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm running the copy database wizard on a 2008 R2 instance of SQL Server.

The database I want to copy is a SQL 2000 database.
I'm copy that database to another SQL SErver 2008 R2.

The wizard uses SQL authentication for both servers, and both are sysadmins.

When I run it, I get the following error (FYI I have tried both copying the logins and leaving them out):

> Event Name: OnError
>    Message: ERROR : errorCode=-1073548784 description=Executing the query "sys.sp_addrolemember @rolename = N'RandomRoleName..." failed with the following error: "The role 'RandomRoleName' does not exist in the current database.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
>    helpFile= helpContext=0 idofInterfaceWithError={C81DFC5A-3B22-4DA3-BD3B-10BF861A7F9C}
>   StackTrace:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dts.DtsTransferProvider.ExecuteTransfer()
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer.TransferData()
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.TransferObjectsTask.TransferObjectsTask.TransferDatabasesUsingSMOTransfer()

Any help would be appreciated!

Jim

Comment: Did you check the role name Under Security -> Role -> ?

Comment: @SQL I assume you mean in the source database? Yes... that's where the wizard is picking up the role from.

Comment: Of course the _real_ reason for that error is because some scripting kiddie at the [small](http://www.english-for-students.com/micro.html) soft company didn't check for a nil pointer in their code (they probably call it a null pointer though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The copy wizard had missed some security and IIRC it's caused by subtle differences in security tables, principals etc between the 2 versions.

Frankly, the easiest way is to do one of these two:

- backup/restore
- detach, copy, attach

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is dont use the copy database wizard.  Create a full backup of the database on the 2000 server and then restore it on the 2008 server.

If you google "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dts.DtsTransferProvider.ExecuteTransfer Copy Database Wizard"  you will find that many many people have gotten this same error or other nearly identical smo errors... no-one appears to have gotten past it.

That's isn't to say its impossible... just, restoring a backup is so much easier then the wizard or troubleshooting the wizard.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have access to the O/S and can't get it, another option is to create the missing role(s) in the background as the copy runs.
 You have to catch it between the creation of the files and when it tries to reference the roles, but there are a few seconds in which to create them if you keep clicking execute - I managed to create 9 roles.
Unfortunately, you'll end up with the roles in another database too (while yours cannot be used) so those need to be deleted.

Of course, this is only an option when you really can't use the other method.

Answer (score 1):

Though the answer which is using the backup technique solves the problem generally, after facing the same issue several times, I was able to trace down the root of the problem using the Event Viewer of Windows to that the Database Copy wizard, using the SQL Agent, will eventually create a Job for the agent to run, after which the Agent will run **using its own credentials** (i.e. the credentials that you can look up in Windows Services, in my case, `NT Service\SQLAgent$SQL2014`)

All you need to do is to go the folder where SQL Server creates DB files (e.g. `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQL2014\MSSQL\DATA` by default for SQL 2014) and give the SQL Agent windows user write/read access on the folder.

Answer (score 0):

The reason can be that a file with the new Database name already exist on the filesystem. We encountered this when we renamed Database X to X_Old, and tried to copy database Y to X. This cannot be done, because database X_Old is still associated with the filename X.

Either delete the conflicting database, or rename the file on the file system.

See http://codecopy.wordpress.com/2012/01/03/error-while-copying-a-database/